# My variables don't want to show up even after i define them it gives me an error that the variable doesn't exist

Tags: python, variables

[this is the problem with the code because I don't know how to properly explain it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY46y.png)

Here is the code in typed form as well

```
        def convert6(tog = [0]):

        tog[0] = not tog[0]
        if tog[0]:
            print('Server DIF Hard ON')
            difHardS = 1

        else:
            print('Server DIF Hard OFF')
            difHardS = 0

    button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Hard", command=convert6, height=2, width=20)
    button3.pack()
if difHardS = 1:
```

Comment: Define it once more outside pf the function, this way it doesnt get defined until the function gets called

Comment: ```global difHardS = 1``` Try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `difHardS` variable within the method (I assume) which is nowhere defined in the method. This is the problem that the editor describes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `global difHardS` to call this variable inside the function

```py
difHardS = 0  # or the value you choose
        def convert6(tog = [0]):
            global difHardS
            tog[0] = not tog[0]
            if tog[0]:
                print('Server DIF Hard ON')
                difHardS = 1

            else:
                print('Server DIF Hard OFF')
                difHardS = 0

    button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Hard", command=convert6, height=2, width=20)
    button3.pack()
if difHardS == 1:  # Use two == operator here.
```

I can only fix the errors you are highlighted in the image. For more fixes, ask in comments